# mysql_num_rows returns 1

Tags: php, mysql

Why does the code below  returns 1 although there is no elements in the field group_members ?

```
$conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);

@mysql_select_db($db);

$sql = "
    SELECT 
        group_members
    FROM
        tbl_group
    WHERE
        group_id = '6'      
";

$res = mysql_query($sql);

$rows = mysql_num_rows($res);

echo $rows;
```

?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL you wrote will select all rows with `group_id = 6` and then return the value of the field `group_members` regardless the content. To get what you want, try:

```
SELECT group_members FROM tbl_group WHERE group_id = 6 AND group_members <> '' // Depending on type might also be <> NULL or <> 0
```

Comment: It's the unequal operator. Basically it means: Select all entries from the table where group_id is 6 and group_members is not empty. The actual syntax depends on the type of the group_members field.

Answer (score 1):

You have 1 record stored in `tbl_group where group_id = '6'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for `group_id = 6` in phpmyadmin in search tab. you can check for 6 in `group_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Check using phpmyadmin, how many rows have group id = 6.